# Exploring the Similarity of Sibling’s Voices Using Automatic Speaker Recognition

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing

I want to start project on Exploring the Similarity of Sibling’s Voices Using Automatic Speaker Recognition

> Everyone has a unique voice, because of the different structure of their articulatory organs. Some people have similar voices due to biological similarity or someone is mimicking them. This similarity raises a security concern. Several studies tried to distinguish between similar voices of people using speaker recognition techniques. Speaker recognition not only models an individual’s voice but also their speaking habits. This study surveys the use of automatic speaker recognition techniques in order to explore the similarity between siblings. This includes comparing the performance of several models, such as artificial neural networks (ANNs), Gaussian mixture model (GMM) and i-vector. In addition, a dataset of sibling speech is recorded and processed to be available for public research.

and **want to know what to learn in order to make this project and if there any recommended recourses?**